# Tor Hidden Service v3 'INTRO-AUTH' Client Authentication

Tags: onion-services

In the Tor hidden service v3 protocol spec https://github.com/FiloSottile/torspec/blob/master/rend-spec-v3.txt there are 2 types of client authentication described, `HS-DESC-ENC` which uses an x25519 keypair, and `INTRO-AUTH` which uses an ed25519 keypair. Below excerpt from the spec.

```
   - An x25519 keypair used to compute decryption keys that allow the client to
     decrypt the hidden service descriptor. See [HS-DESC-ENC].

   - An ed25519 keypair which allows the client to compute signatures which
     prove to the hidden service that the client is authorized. These
     signatures are inserted into the INTRODUCE1 cell, and without them the
     introduction to the hidden service cannot be completed. See [INTRO-AUTH].
```

The first type, `HS-DESC-ENC`, is already easily usable by generating an x25519 keypair and adding it to the client authorzation folder.

However, I am wondering if the second `INTRO-AUTH` authorization method is usable yet, and how to set it up.

I think what I'm trying to do requires `INTRO-AUTH` specifically: I want to be able to issue every user of a hidden service their own client auth key, and be able to tell when each key is used, eventually set usage limits (eg, limited to 1 connection at a time), etc. I'm guessing this isn't possible with `HS-DESC-ENC` as everyone decrypts the same hidden service descriptor, so the hidden service can't tell which key is being used to connect, only that the client had *a* valid key. But for the hidden service to validate the client's digital signature in `INTRO-AUTH` it would have to know for certain which key was used, which hopefully won't be too difficult to extract.

Comment: I'll try to look into this also when I have time. I just wanted to say make sure you're reading the latest official version of the documentation first.  https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/

Comment: @JSEvans https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v3.txt#n625 This says "client auth is implemented" but not sure if that means just the `HS-DESC-ENC` auth.